# Almost everywhere property for a summable function.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$f$ is a summable function.

If $\int_{B}fdm=0$ for any measurable subset $B\subset A$ and $B\neq A$, then $f=0$ a.e on $A$ .

I started off by letting $m(\{x\in A|f(x)\neq 0\})>0$. Since $m(\{x\in A|f(x)\neq 0\}) = m(\{x\in A|f(x)>0\}\cup m(\{x\in A|f(x)<0\})$, one of them must have positive measure.

I am able to show that if $m(\{x\in A|f(x)>0\}>0$, contradiction occurs. But I was unable to show contradiction when $m(\{x\in A|f(x)<0\})>0$. Any particular hint for this part ?

Comment: if you are able to show the first inequality the second follows by applying the same reasoning (whatever it was) to $-f$. If not then something is fishy with your proof.

Comment: The problem with the second inequality is it is "less than". I wrote $m\{x\in A|f(x)<0\})$ as union of $m(\{x\in A|f(x)\leq\frac{-1}{n}\})$ , then I am unable to continue the proof anymore because here, $f(x)\leq\frac{-1}{n}$

Comment: Do you literally mean I put $m(\{x\in A|-f(x)>\frac{1}{n}\})$ and show that $\int_{A}-fdm>0$?

Comment: Is $A$ supposed to be measurable? I don't see that it is called out, and actually the result is trivial if it is (let $B = A\setminus\{a\}$ for some $a \in A$). But if it isn't, then you have no guarantee that the subsets you've defined are measurable either. .

Comment: The assumptions you made do not take into account the sign of $f$ in any way, nor does the claim. So whatever proof you found for your first inequality (and I really don't care about the details and I don't want to look into them), it must apply to both $f$ and $-f$. Just let $g = -f $ and do with $g$ whatever you did with $f$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, it is supposed to be bounded measurable set.

Comment: @Thomas , okay, I get what you meant. Thanks